# Prevent STS4 from launching browser when run?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I have a Spring Boot application with only api rest calls.

Everytime I press the "run on server" button a browser is launched trying to access the current file. Of course it always prompt an error:

[image: Error Prompt]

Sorry for the image being in Spanish. It basically says that cannot download the resource.

My question is how to avoid this browser from launching everytime I run my application.

Thanks.

Comment: I know that this is not exactly answering your question, but why don't you start your Spring Boot app with the embedded server as a standard Spring Boot app? (instead of running it on a separate server instance) It could make things easier.

Comment: @MartinLippert I don't really understand what are you asking me to do. My spring aplication need to be deployed as a war. It's my first project using STS (before I used InteliJ). I switched to STS because it let me compile the project as a war instead of jar. I don't know if this has something to do. Anyway I already found a solution so maybe its best if I post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. Here is what I did:

Go to `Window > Preferences > General > Web Browser > New...`

Add a new browser with:

- name = `NO BROWSER` (or whatever you want)
- location = `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`
- parameters = `/c`

Press OK.

Finally select `Use external web browser`, select the browser we just added and press `Apply and Close`.

The browser configuration should look like this.

[image: Web Browser configuration]

Instead of using the cmd you could use a batch/shell script that does nothing (without the /c parameter which is only needed for the cmd to do nothing).

**NOTE**: This solution is applied to the IDE not to the project.